# Use presentModalViewController but with modeUIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

How is it possible that I change the transition for presenting a modal view controller. Is it possible that the presenting transition is using the default UIModalTransitionStyle....

```
UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical = 0,
UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal,
UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve,
UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl,
```

but the dismiss transition is using the UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp transition. Important is that I don't want to use the UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl it should be the CurlUp one.

Sadly the following code doesn't work:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:self.parentViewController.parentViewController.parentViewController.view duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp completion:^(BOOL finished) {....}];
```

Maybe it has something to do that the view controller is displayed in modal mode.

It would be nice if someone can help.

Comment: By the way, `presentModalViewController` has been deprecated. You can use `presentViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

It feels kludgy, but you can do this by animating the transition of adding your destination view controller's view, but on the completion of that, you immediately remove it again and then properly transition to it via the `presentViewController` (this time without animation, since the visual effect has already been rendered).

I do this in a subclassed custom `UIStoryboardSegue` (you didn't say NIBs or storyboard, but the concept is the same):

```
- (void)perform
{
    UIViewController *src = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *dst = self.destinationViewController;

    [UIView transitionWithView:src.navigationController.view
                      duration:0.75
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                    animations:^{
                        [src.navigationController.view addSubview:dst.view];
                    }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        [dst.view removeFromSuperview];
                        [src presentViewController:dst animated:NO completion:nil];
                    }];
}
```

Clearly, if your source view controller doesn't have a navigation controller, you would replace those "`src.navigationController.view`" with just "`src.view`". But hopefully this gives you the idea.

And, anticipating the logical follow-up question, when dismissing the view controller, I have a button hooked up to an `IBAction`:

```
- (IBAction)doneButton:(id)sender 
{
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view.superview
                      duration:0.75
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                    animations:^{
                        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
                    }
                    completion:nil];
}
```